# How to change color of leaflet marker svg

Tags: javascript, leaflet

how can i change only the color of the marker? previously i used just two svgs, one that is active and one that is not, now i wanted to add more icons and making two copies of each icon just to show its active state is not very good approach ig, what can i do?
i tried with divIcon and replacing its html but that didnt work either

```
icon = L.divIcon({
    className: "custom-icon",
    html: iconSvg,
    iconSize: [24, 24],
    iconAnchor: [12, 12],
  });

        active.options.icon.options.html.replace(
          'fill="#FFD400"',
          'fill="#FF1900"'
        );
```

Comment: Why bother so much?
Remove "fill" from the svg file and control it with `.cutom-icon { fill: red; }`
As you show, if you use an svg file you will not change the color.
You can change the colors by changing the className, and it is best to add a new class to the basic className, e.g. .red, a class that will add fill red, etc.

Comment: @GrzegorzT. thats a good idea, i found that you can use hue rotate on it but this is even better, ty
edit: nvm this doesnt work, i will stick to hue rotate

Comment: Here is an example of how to change the color of SVG markers [svg-markers-width-legends](https://tomickigrzegorz.github.io/leaflet-examples/#13.svg-markers-width-legends) You can use it and you will also find something for yourself in these examples.